# PHP and Javascript Login doesn't work despite correct username and password

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send data between a .js and a .php file for login. I've managed to send the data over from the js to the php using ajax, however I am having some difficulty with the login checking in the .php file, the loop always returns  "failed" in firebug regardless if the username and password is correct or not.

I've tried to match the username and password but it doesn't seem to be working how I want it to. I'm new at this so I probably made a mistake, but have no idea what is wrong. I've checked various questions similar to this, but none of them were able to help. Would appreciate if I could get some help! Here are the codes:

**.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#login").click(function() {

        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        //checking for blank fields
        if (email == '' || password == '') {
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("border", "2px solid red");
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("box-shadow", "0 0 3px red");
            alert("Please fill up all the fields");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/Reward/applogin.php",
                    data: {log_email: JSON.stringify(email), log_pwd: JSON.stringify(password)},
                    dataType: 'JSONP',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,

                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        if (data == 'Invalid Email') 
                        {
                            $('input[type="text"]').css({
                                "border": "2px solid red",
                                "box-shadow": "0 0 3px red"
                            });
                            $('input[type="password"]').css({
                                "border": "2px solid #00F5FF",
                                "box-shadow": "0 0 5px #00F5FF"
                            });
                            alert(data);
                        } 
                        else if (data == "Email or Password is incorrect") 
                        {
                            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({
                                "border": "2px solid red",
                                "box-shadow": "0 0 3px red"
                            });
                            alert(data);
                        } 
                        else if (data == "Successfully Logged in") 
                        {
                            alert("Success");
                            $("form")[0].reset();
                            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({
                                "border": "2px solid #00F5FF",
                                "box-shadow": "0 0 5px #00F5FF"
                            });

                            alert(data);
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            alert(data);
                        }

                    }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

**.php**

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require 'dbcon.php';

if((isset($_POST["log_email"])) && (isset($_POST["log_pwd"]))) 
{
    require 'dbcon.php';
    $log_email = json_decode($_POST["log_email"]);
    $log_pwd = json_decode($_POST["log_pwd"]);

    $result = $con->prepare("SELECT `acc_email`, `acc_pwd` FROM `account` WHERE `acc_email` = ?");
    $result->bind_param('s', $log_email);
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($acc_email, $acc_pwd);

    if($result->fetch())
      {
        if ($acc_email == $log_email && $acc_pwd == $log_pwd) 
        {
          $data="Successfully Logged in";
          echo json_encode ($data);
        }
        else
        {
          $data="Email or Password is incorrect";
          echo json_encode($data);
        }
      }
    else
      {
        echo json_encode ("Failed");
      }  
    //connection closed
    mysqli_close ($con);
}

else
{
    echo json_encode ("Super Failed");
}
?>
```

EDIT: I've tried using a test .php file to see if it would make any difference. Seems like the "if" loop is being ignored and it jumps straight to the "else" part and echoes "u lose" as a response in firebug. If i remove the else part, there is no response at all.

Here is the test .php file I used:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['log_email']))
{
        echo json_encode("blablabla");
}
else 
{
  echo json_encode("u lose");
}

?>
```

Comment: You only have 1 placeholder. You are trying to bind 2 values. You dont need to escape when binding. You should hash your passwords, if you arent already. You also don't need the `$acc_email == $log_email` you know it matches if you get a return.

Comment: *everytime you store an unhashed password, root moves a kitten to /dev/null!* use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I've found that the problem is with the datatype I used to send the Ajax request. I referred to this link http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/07/09/how-to-access-cross-domain-data-with-ajax-using-jsonp-jquery-and-php/ for help, and it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is here:

```
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT `acc_email`, `acc_pwd` FROM `account` WHERE `acc_email` = ?");
$result->bind_param('ss', $log_email, $log_pwd);
```

Change the second line in this way:

```
$result->bind_param('s', $log_email);
```

You only need to compare the email, not the password and the email.

Now, this fragment is also unnecessary:

```
$acc_email = $acc_email;
$acc_pwd = $acc_pwd;
```

So your function should looks like this:

```
<?php

require 'dbcon.php';

if(isset($_POST["log_email"]) && isset($_POST["log_pwd"])) 
{
    require 'dbcon.php';
    $log_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["log_email"]);
    $log_pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["log_pwd"]);

    $result = $con->prepare("SELECT `acc_email`, `acc_pwd` FROM `account` WHERE `acc_email` = ?");
    $result->bind_param('s', $log_email);
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($acc_email, $acc_pwd);

    if($result->fetch())
      {
        if ($acc_email == $log_email && $acc_pwd == $log_pwd) 
        {
           echo json_encode ("Successfully Logged in");
        }else{
            echo json_encode("Email or Password is incorrect");
        }
      }
    else
      {
        echo json_encode ("Failed");
      }  
    //connection closed
    mysqli_close ($con);
}else{
    echo json_encode ("Failed");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this out however the loop still only returns the very last echo 'echo json_encode ("Failed");' in which I changed the "Failed" to something else to make sure.